# overlaying two plots with the same x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to overlay these two below diagrams:

[image]

I am using the code below to do that:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [7.50, 3.50]
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True
overlapping = 0.150
line1 = plt.plot(plot_1, c='red', alpha=overlapping, lw=5)
line2 = plt.plot(plot_2, c='green', alpha=overlapping, lw=5)
plt.show()

enter code here
```

But, the problem is in the resulted diagram I got two axis each one dedicated to y-exis of the initial diagrams. The thing that i need is plotting a diagram, which has x-axis as the same as the initial diagrams.

Can someone let me know how can i correct my code?

my resulted incorrect diagram is:

[image]

Comment: How did you generate the second graph? You should first set up an axes `ax = plot.subplot()`, then use `ax.plot` instead of `plt.plot`.

Comment: when you don't pass x-values, the x-values are assigned as `range(len(y_values))`

Answer (score 0):

You can do just something like the following:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0)

y_1 = 25 * (1-np.exp(-10*x**2))
y_2 = y_1 * 0.7

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y_1)
plt.plot(x, y_2)
```

[image]